# can't change the background color of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, colors

I am changing a theme like (blue,grey) which is working pretty fine and when my theme got changed, i also want to change the dropdown menu background color which right now is #333.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
css:
----
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-submenu:hover>a,.dropdown-submenu:focus>a
{

    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#ffffff; 
    background:#333;
}

#photo
{
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background: #031;
}


javascript:
-----------

function switchTheme(themename) 
{
    var cookieInfo = "theme = " + themename;
    document.cookie = cookieInfo;

    var classes = $("body").prop("class").split(" ");
    _.each(classes, function(c) 
    {
       if (_.string.startsWith(c, 'theme-'))
                $("body").removeClass(c);
    });

    $("body").addClass(themename);

    var color = '#031';
    if(themename == 'theme-grey')
    {
        color = '#333';
    }
    else if(themename == 'theme-blue')
    {
        color = '#034';
    }
    document.getElementById('photo').style.background = color; //this works
    document.getElementById('dropdown-menu>li>a').style.background = color; // this is not working. why?
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using css expressions for locating dom element with `document.getElementById('dropdown-menu>li>a')`

Comment: what should is use then?

Comment: You will have to wrap the `dropdown-menu` into a div with an ID and then try using your code with `document.getElementById(<div id>).style.background = ...`